# multiband raster: set no data values to 255,255,255,255

Tags: raster, arcmap, raster-calculator

ArcMap 10.2:

I have a 4 band raster dataset (img-file) with no data values.
I want that the no data values appear in white (255,255,255) and therefore want to change it to these values.
I know how to do it with a 1 band raster as explained here:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/h-changing-nodata-cells-to-a-value.htm

```
Identify the NoData locations with the IsNull tool:

    Input raster : InRas1

    Output raster : OutNullRas

Use Con on the results to give the original NoData areas a value:

    Input conditional raster : OutNullRas

    Expression : "Value = 1"

    Input true raster or constant value : 100

    Input false raster or constant value : InRas1

    Output raster : NullTo100_Ras
```

Is this working with a 4 band raster in a different way?

Comment: Take a look at Raster Calculator (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm). You should be able to apply similar logic to each of the four bands in your raster.

Comment: I ve tried in Raster Calculator with:
Con("20cm.img - Layer_1"=0,255), Con("20cm.img - Layer_2"=0,255), Con("20cm.img - Layer_3"=0,255), Con("20cm.img - Layer_4"=0,255) but it produces an error?!

in this case i want to change the value 0 to 255 which is also OK.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've done so far and the error you are getting. The error text will be helpful in deciphering what the problem is.